# Pandas: SettingWithCopyWarning Try using .loc

Tags: python, pandas

I know that this is a very popular error, however, in my case, I was not able to figure out why that happening to me.

I am getting:

```
 SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

    See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
      df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'], unit='ms')
    : SettingWithCopyWarning: 
    A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
    Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead
```

code:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame


def filter_df(df: DataFrame, symbol: str):
    return df.loc[(df['symbol'] == symbol)]


def convert_time(df):
    df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'], unit='ms')
    return df


df = pd.read_hdf(path_or_buf='/tmp/data/file.h5')
df = filter(df, 'AAA')
df = convert_time(df)
```

Could you please help me to figure out why I am getting such warning?

Comment: you mean `df = filter_df(df...`?

Answer (score 5):

It is a well documented warning.
To solve

```
df.loc[:,'time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'], unit='ms')
```

This happens because `df['time']` is a view, not the real data you would like to edit.
Please check elsewhere in the code as this warning will popup eveytime you assing a column like

```
   df[column_name]=something
```

The correct is

```
   df.loc[:, column_name]=something
```